# Windows 10: How do I set a whitelist only policy (No GPO)

Tags: windows, networking, windows-10

So I have 5 laptops we need on a very restrictive policy. We do NOT have Active Directory, we use Azure-AD only.
These laptops cannot access ANY website except 3. But I also need to allow TeamViewer, InTune MDM, Windows Update, and Office 365.

The three websites that need to be accessed must be accessed via Google Chrome

What is the easiest way to do this? I attempted doing a hosts file update, but did not work. I found this: [Allow only white-listed sites on Windows 10](https://superuser.com/questions/988547/allow-only-white-listed-sites-on-windows-10)
I tried modifying the Hosts file, rebooted the machine, and all of the "null routes" didn't work. It was as if the host file was completely ignored. Nothing changed.

We're on Windows 10 Pro, so the family/parental controls do not work and require Microsoft accounts to set and modify which is not acceptable.

I have read a few other topics on here discussing similar tactics, but I have been unable to get them to work. These need to be machine specific, not network/organization-wide, what is the simplest solution to this? I feel like I am missing something

Comment: How reliable do you expect this to be? Because it won’t be if it’s enforced by the machine itself.

Comment: I need good reliability. These are patients at a detox clinic who need a computer to enter journal entries on two websites, and check managed email messages from a third site.

The whole mission is to prevent these users from accessing anything other than those 3 sites.

Comment: So what you’re saying is that you control the network, right? Then that’s where you’ll have to enforce this policy.

Comment: You could do it with `ROUTE ADD` and block everything with a lower metric than the default route with a dummy Default Gateway to point traffic to no where but then have lower metric routes with the public IP address or address ranges to the allowed resources with the legit DG but you would need to know the public IP addresses or whatever with this method. Good luck with that and Team Viewer though but perhaps you script it all out, and then have ADD and DELETE script and have restriction valid when drug addicted people have physical access... Updates, etc. at 12 AM - 4 AM for example.—Rules!

Comment: If you don't lock the machine permissions down otherwise, say an IT drug addict to heroin comes in shaking and needs drug rehab real bad—He could go over to the machine, type in some `ROUTE DELETE` commands and such and mess your route table hack all up allowing all his fellow colleagues to browse porn and infect the machine with malicious software. Long story short, there are different levels to enforce such rules but what level you use and who you allow to also make such changes may matter—security by obscurity—what are you trying to protect or else prevent exactly—porn from smart phones.

Answer (score 0):

So here is what I ended up doing and worked PERFECTLY (for us) I used Windows Advanced Firewall to block ALL incoming and outgoing.

Then I set three Outgoing Rules to Allow Chrome to access certain websites and Allowed TeamViewer for our remote support.

This method blocks IE and Edge from even connecting. I then changed the local user account that the Clients would be using to GUEST.

This locked down everything, spend over an hour trying to break it and have been (successfully) unsuccessful.

Thank you all for the Tips, they ultimately led me to the steps I took