# How to whitelist websites (not blacklist) in hosts files?

Tags: localhost, hosts-file, blacklist, whitelist

I'm trying to make it easy to avoid random distracting websites. I'd like to have my host file set up to only allow a few websites. Everything else should be blocked.

I can't get this to work. This is what I was using: [Allow only white-listed sites on Windows 10](https://superuser.com/questions/988547/allow-only-white-listed-sites-on-windows-10)

This is an example of what doesn't work. I've tried with 127.0.0.1 and 0.0.0.0:

```
# whitelist
142.251.215.238 google.com 

# blacklist
127.0.0.1 .com
# 0.0.0.0 .com
```

Blacklisting specific websites works fine, it's just whitelisting a few and then blacklisting everything else that doesn't.

I know there's chrome extensions like BlockSite, but I'd prefer to control this myself.

Comment: Whitelisting is possible if you disable DNS in your network or for that PC and thus only the entries in hosts file remain (place there the sites and their real IP). Problem is that you have to list every host name a website uses and adapt all changes manually. Thus this way is possible but not realistic for more than one or two websites. I would recommend to find a local DNS proxy that runs locally and allows to filter the DNS requests based on patterns, so only requests for white-listed domains including subdomains are forwarded to the real DNS server.